# How to get first date of the week based on week number and year in Moment.js?

Tags: momentjs

I tried to get the start date of a specific week in Moment.js from the week number and year by doing `moment().year(...).isoWeek(...).startOf('isoWeek')`

But It seems that this function is not always returning the correct date.
For example when I live in England and a week always starts on a monday.
We should get 31 Dec 2018 when we ask for the first day of week 1, 2019.

This wasn't the case on 31 Dec 2018 as the result I received was 30 Dec 2019 as the begin date of week 1, 2019. See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rLjQx/161193/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found the solution I was looking for

`moment()
.isoWeekYear(year)
.isoWeek(week)
.startOf('week')`

Comment: startOf('week') gives Sunday as the first day of the week. If you want the week to start from Monday, "isoWeek" should be used like this.
const firstDateOftheWeek =  moment().isoWeekYear(year).isoWeek(week).startOf('isoWeek').

Answer (score 0):

Please note that, as [i18n](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/) section of the docs states:

> By default, Moment.js comes with English (United States) locale strings. If you need other locales, you can load them into Moment.js for later use.

So if you want to use `en-gb` locale you have explicitly load it (in the browser, you can use [`en-gb.js`](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/locale/en-gb.js) file or [`moment-with-locales.js`](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment-with-locales.js) and then set locale using [`moment.locale('en-gb')`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/)).

You don't have to use [`year()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/year/) setter, because it sets the year to `2019` and `moment().year(2019).isoWeek(1)` gives you the first isoweek of the **`2020`**. You can create a moment object for a given year using [`moment({y: year})`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/object/) instead.

You have to use [`week()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/week/) instead of [`isoWeek`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/iso-week/) if you want locale dependent results:

> Because different locales define week of year numbering differently, Moment.js added `moment#week` to get/set the localized week of the year.
>
> The week of the year varies depending on which day is the first day of the week (Sunday, Monday, etc), and which week is the first week of the year.

Here a full code sample:

```js
// Set locale to British English
moment.locale('en-gb');
var year = 2019;
var firstMonday = moment({y: year}) // get first day of the given year
    .week(1) // get the first week according locale
    .startOf('week'); // get the first day of the week according locale
// Show result
console.log(firstMonday.format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

You can use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to display the value of a moment object.

Comment: I was aware that I had to use locale and set it to the correct location. But I wasn't able to get it working in my snippet.

Comment: For week and year I wanted to use the global numbering as later on we will have different locations in our project. That's why i need to use the isoWeek and isoWeekYear.